# How could I have an object's Z axis align with the first derivative of is location F-Curve

Tags: animation, constraints, mathematics, fcurves

I want an object to follow a path in space (specified via F-Curves, or by clamping to a Bezier curve), but I want the Z axis of this object to always be tangent to this trajectory (the same way that the engine of a train is approximately tangent to the train tracks).

I've tried using constraints: having an empty move along the "train tracks", and my object following closely behind, using a `track-to` constraint (so the object's Z points to the empty). I've paired this with a `limit distance` constraint (target is again the empty), but the result is not visually convincing -- it looks like the object is short-cutting the turns, as opposed to staying on the "train tracks".

Comment: i would use this method for a train. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133032/15543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is for an object to move along a curve (e.g. Bezier) with one of its axis aligned with the curve's first derivative, as suggested by @atomicbezierslinger, you can use a `follow path` constraint. For example, if we want the object's Z axis to be aligned with the curve's tangent:

1. Set `Follow  Curve` to true.
2. Set the `Forward` axis to `Z`
3. Set the `Up` axis to either `X` or `Y` (setting to `Z` will not work, and the object might not move at all).

Comment: The `Follow Path` constraint works if I select as `Forward` the `X` or `Y` axis, but not the `Z` axis (which is the one I want). When I select as `Forward` the `Z` axis, nothing happens -- the object is static at its location, not moving during the whole animation.

Comment: I see a dotted blue straight line from the center of the object to a point traveling along the Bezier curve, but the object itself remains static.

Comment: I got it to work by rotating the object and using the -Y axis, but I still don't know why the `Forward = Z` does not work.

Comment: The problem was that both the `Forward` and the `Up` axes were set to `Z`. If `Forward` is set to `Z`, then up needs to be set to either `X` or `Y`.