# please help me with the drivers

Tags: drivers

help me with the drivers please
i am trying to make the wheel  rotate always forward using drivers  but when i change the Direction of the variable (cube ) , the wheel start to rotate in the negative Direction

it should always rotate  forward around the the x axis in the local transformation

this is the images help me understand please
[image] 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HezTZ.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[the file link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jXrEcTKvtL8G3VXRitG-b0Min-jLizzq)

Comment: For driving along a path https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133032/15543  The drivers can be driven by curve modified mesh location z (in case of link example)  Search for the blender car rigs of Roubal who uses this setup.

Comment: thank u so much this will help for sure 
but do u know how to make it work without the the curve ?

Comment: To put this another way. What you see is the result  of driving the rotation with transform channel y . eg as it travels around a unit circle path, local centre (0, 0)  y will oscillate between -1 and 1. , whereas for each lap we travel 2pi.  Could go in the x direction infinitely and never spin the wheels..  The set-up suggested in comment lets you keyframe in the distance traveled by  the curve modified mesh.  Your images suggest you are using a path.