# Rigging train wheels

Tags: rigging

I'm creating an animation with a steam train and I need to make the front wheels selected to turn and slide from side to side. I plan to use path follow to make the main thing move but I need to make the wheels also turn. I need to find a tutorial that shows how to make the train follow a path and have the wheels rotate and slide so that it looks like it's going around a curve. Kinda like a caravan behind a car.[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes you can, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach. 
If your entire train is following the path it might work though. Make sure the path has linear interpolation. 
use the main (parent bone) to follow the path.
Use a bone between the wheels to follow the path inheriting the rotation. (both best with constraints, not parenting) offset the front wheel bone path position. 
use copy rotation or transforms constraints to make the wheels turn with the path. 
But it's going to be quite tedious I'm afraid

Comment: Are the wheels on bogies?

Comment: May be of use https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-like-train-on-a-track-snake/133032?r=SearchResults&s=1|31.2129#133032 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164883/calculate-spheres-rotation-for-rolling  The latter requires you to have the track length.