# Calculate sphere's rotation for rolling

Tags: animation, mathematics

Let's say that there is a sphere whose x,y,z dimensions are `d`. So, the circumference is `d*pi`. Now, the sphere is rolling on a surface. The `z` will stay the same, but the x,y locations are moved from `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)`. Assuming that the initial rotation is `(0,0,0)`, can I calculate the rotation values for the last frame, so that I could make the rolling animation realistic? I mean, the sphere has some texture so that if it does not rotate, it will look as if it is sliding on the surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple driver**

For constant rotation of a sphere / circle

[image]
*Think I used a poor choice of frame rate for gif*

The distance a rolling circle travels is `radius * angle`  with angle in radians. 
Circumference is special case of arc length. Gives the distance traveled for one full revolution, or 360 degrees or `2 * pi` radians.

The angle `theta` rolled for a distance `d`

```
theta = d / radius
```

Set up a simple driver on the y rotation of a sphere based on its x location, and half a dimension as radius.  Using self on drivers rather than a more traditional driver variable approach (*[Which removes warning](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134270/use-self-and-the-slow-python-expression)*)

[image]
*Drivers Editior*

[image]
*Properties panel*

```
2 * self.location.x /  self.dimensions.x
```

*any dimension (diameter) could be used, or hardcoded*

Using this our ball rolls about y as it travels along x.

To change the direction, possibly the simplest is to parent the whole setup to an empty.  *Or use angle axis rotation*

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do a realistic animation you should use rigid bodies. It's very easy. Using maths your gonna get crazy because there is a lot of things to consider: gravity friction etc 
there is a tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WWmGp4jEog

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't trying to be perfectly realistic, so gravity, friction, etc are probably not needed. And I assumed a flat surface. And moving a little bit (maybe about half of the circumference). I wondered what the last frame's rotation should be to make it look like rolling. Even in that case, is the calculation complicated?

Comment: If using rigids is dead easy, please help making this site better and add some steps on how to achieve this to your answer, links always can go down. Cheers!