# "Use self" doesn't work?

Tags: rigging, drivers

I'm currently working with drivers in Blender 2.81 and want to use `self` but it doesn't work.

For example drive the rotation by the location, I'm adding a driver to the rotation, check the *Use Self* box and write `self.location.x`

Blender return the message: `ERROR Invalid Python expression`.

Have I missed something, is it a bug?

edit:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of driver editor.  Recent example doing just this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164893/15543

Comment: also post any error message that may be printed to console re the error in your expression. Make sure there is no leading spaces in expression for example.  Look for _"Error in Driver: The following Python expression failed:"_

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on 2.9. Problem is still here.
Allowing auto run python scripts fixed it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Look in the system console.**

*As an addendum to the accepted answer, to use self in drivers requires enabling auto-run python scripts. However will also get an invalid expression python error, if ... you have an invalid expression.*

When you get an error in a driver expression look at the system console.

[Where does console output go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go)

[Use self and the slow python expression](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134270/use-self-and-the-slow-python-expression)

Turning off allow auto-run python scripts with use self can lead to invalid expression error.. looking at console.

```
BPY_driver_eval() - restricted access disallows name 'location', enable auto-execution to support

Error in Driver: The following Python expression failed:
'self.location.x'
```

Will give a big tip that checking enable auto run fixes this... but as demonstrated here

[How to use a custom property of an object as input for a driver?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207869/how-to-use-a-custom-property-of-an-object-as-input-for-a-driver) an error in the driver expression can also produce an invalid python expression error message.

So for example  accidentally on purpose making a typo

[image]
*Will look like this with or without auto run python scripts*

```
self.lodation.x
```

**With python auto run OFF error**

```
    BPY_driver_eval() - restricted access disallows name 'lodation', enable auto-execution to support

Error in Driver: The following Python expression failed:
    'self.lodation.x'
```

**With python auto run ON error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<bpy driver>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'lodation'
```