# How to use a custom property of an object as input for a driver?

Tags: light, drivers

I would like to be able to control the power/energy of multiple lamps using a driver.

My idea is to have an empty that I would move on the Z axis between 0 and 1 to multiply the energy of each lamp.

On the lamp power attribute, I have [Use Self enabled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165093/use-self-doesnt-work) and this driver expression:

```
self.energy * var
```

[image]

**Edit**

It seems to provoke a kind of expression loop, and the value is increasing exponentially.
So I guess my original "power" value should be defined elsewhere, maybe as a custom property of my lamp object ?

[image]

How could I link one to my driver expression?

Comment: IMO at issue here is `self.energy` is the power field you are driving. I don't get an error for this, but do get a constantly growing result.. which may lead to an error.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46903/how-to-view-python-error-messages re seeing the error message given, and post into question.

Comment: "This question already has an answer here" - nope, does not work with autorun python scripts.

Comment: Please post the error message printed into system console into question & will re-open.  Please also take other note of my comment above in that you are driving the property with itself.

Comment: @batFINGER you were right. I edited the question.

Comment: whoops voted .. meant to give it a python tag first. Will need to wait on other re-open votes. Was an error message being printed to the system console. Don't get that ... end up with Inf or Nan (Infinity, or not a number as result) .. Re custom prop. Add one to lamp (data) called "prop"  replace `self.energy` with `self["prop"]` in expression above.

Comment: it says "key 'power" not found. I do have a "power" custom property set.

Comment: Make sure it is a lamp custom property, not a lamp object custom property, or scene or viewlayer.  Select the lamp object, in python console type in `C.object.data["foogle"] = 1`   There will now be a custom property on lamp named foogle.  Your screen shot above suggests you are in object tab of properties, not in data tab. `C.object["foogle"]` instead of `C.object.data["foogle"]`.   The `self` in driver for this case is `C.object.data`  Or in UI terms First screen shot above (where driver is), is in data tab. Put the custom prop in the that ones "Custom Properties|".

Comment: this time I got it working ! thanks a LOT for your help here.

Comment: @Timaroberts please re-open, Have added an explanation via answer in linked dupe as to why.