# Scripting: Custom Driver does not work

Tags: python, drivers

So for a project I have been working on, I am attempting to angle a plane based on the positions of 10 different points (represented by empties) by means of linear regression. The current code, as well as the driver and input variables, I have created are shown below:

[image]

So far this error keeps popping up:

[image]

I have attempted to use various techniques I found have failed to resolve the problem, so I am wondering whether I did those wrong or the code itself is flawed.

Thanks.

Edit 1:
So after allowing the code to execute, the following error pops up:
[image]

Also, the code for the program is below:

```
import bpy # importing necessary functions
import math
from math import atan
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

def Control_Function(obj_points): # creating driver function

    X_values = [] # obtaning world cordinates
    Y_values = []
    Z_values = []
    for x in range(len(obj_points)):
        coor = obj_points[x]
        X_values.append(coor[0])
        Y_values.append(coor[1])
        Z_values.append(coor[2])

    X_average = np.sum(X_values)/len(X_values) # creating approximate center
    Y_average = np.sum(Y_values)/len(Y_values)
    Z_average = np.sum(Z_values)/len(Z_values)

    X_coor = X_values - X_average # calculating cordinates based on approximate center
    Y_coor = Y_values - Y_average
    Z_coor = Z_values - Z_average

    A = np.zeros((3,3)) # Finding least sqaures regression coefficients
    b = np.zeros((3,1))
    A_two = np.zeros((3,3))
    b_two = np.zeros((3,1))
    A_three = np.zeros((3,3))
    b_three = np.zeros((3,1))
    looptime = len(X_values)
    x = 0
    while x < looptime:
        A_three = A
        b_three = b
        A_two = [[X_coor[x]*X_coor[x] ,X_coor[x]*Y_coor[x] ,X_coor[x]] ,[Y_coor[x]*X_coor[x] ,Y_coor[x]*Y_coor[x] ,Y_coor[x]] ,[X_coor[x] ,Y_coor[x] ,1]]
        b_two = [[Z_coor[x]*X_coor[x]] ,[Z_coor[x]*Y_coor[x]] ,[Z_coor[x]]]
        A = A_two + A_three
        b = b_two + b_three
        x += 1

    A_t = np.transpose(A) # Solving least squares regression
    A_At = np.matmul(A_t,A)
    A_At_inv = inv(np.array(A_At))
    AAt_inv_A_t = np.matmul(A_At_inv,A_t)
    [[a],[b],[c]] = np.matmul(AAt_inv_A_t,b)
    return a ,b ,c

def xanglecalc(p1 ,p2 ,p3 ,p4 ,p5 ,p6 ,p7 ,p8 ,p9 ,p10):
    print(p2)
    in_vector = [p1 ,p2 ,p3 ,p4 ,p5 ,p6 ,p7 ,p8 ,p9 ,p10]
    out_vector = []
    coor = []
    sub_coor = []
    for mat in range(len(in_vector)):
        coor = in_vector[mat]
        sub_coor = coor[4,0:2]
        out_vector.append(sub_coor)
    print(out_vector)
    a ,b ,c = Control_Function(out_vector)
    x_angle = atan(a)
    y_angle = -atan(b)
    return x_angle


def yanglecalc(p1 ,p2 ,p3 ,p4 ,p5 ,p6 ,p7 ,p8 ,p9 ,p10):
    in_vector = [p1 ,p2 ,p3 ,p4 ,p5 ,p6 ,p7 ,p8 ,p9 ,p10]
    out_vector = []
    coor = []
    sub_coor = []
    for mat in range(len(in_vector)):
        coor = in_vector[mat]
        sub_coor = [[coor[4,0]] ,[coor[4,1]] ,[coor[4,2]]]
        out_vector.append(sub_coor)
    a ,b ,c = Control_Function(out_vector)
    x_angle = atan(a)
    y_angle = -atan(b)
    return y_angle

bpy.app.driver_namespace['xangle'] = xanglecalc
bpy.app.driver_namespace['yangle'] = yanglecalc
```

Comment: have you enabled Auto Run Python Scripts in Preferences?  `Save & Load` > `Auto Run Python Scripts`

Comment: Please paste code rather than use a screenshot. That makes it possible for others to examine your code with Python tools.  Likewise please paste tracebacks.  However, as @XY points out, your error message is telling you that in order to use 'angle' you need to enable auto-execution.  See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208196/42221) for more details.

Comment: @XY I was able to run the Python Script, which generated another error that s currently attached as an edit to the main post.

Comment: @MartyFouts I have added the code as you requested, as well as the error that shows when the code is run