# Camera following a circular path around object stops after 1 rotation, I want to have it loop over and over

Tags: animation, camera, tracking

I set my camera to rotate around an object by having it follow a bezier circle, but it stops moving after 1 rotation.I have linked the video here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Jx7.jpg

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23311/cyclic-orbit-animation/23328#23328

Comment: If you set up the follow path constraint as "fixed path" then 0 offset is one end, and 1 the other.  Can use a driver  `(frame % 24) / 24` to make the object continuously circuit  the path every 24 frames.  Last script example sets up orbit on camera to (0, 0, 0).  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176762/15543 Used here (equiv `(frame / 24) % 1`) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165412/15543  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118290/continuous-looping-animation-differing-rotational-speeds

Comment: Are you willing to do it using Python scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

There are options in the *Graph Editor tab : Channels > Extrapolation Mode > Make Cyclic* or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and *Make Cyclic* from *Graph Editor*, that will put your animation in a loop.