# Making a cycloid in blender?

Tags: modeling, physics

For a school project, I'm investigating the brachistochrone curve. As part of this, I want to make a 3D simulation of an object falling down a cycloid, but I'm not sure how I would actually go about making the cycloid?
[image: This is the cycloid curve]

Comment: Another way (though @MartyFotus has a more *correct* approach) is to use dynamic paint. With this, you can actually '*track*' the point on the circle as it moves.

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165190/how-to-do-trammel-of-archimedes-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* add-on in your preferences.

This will allow you to add a Mesh -> Math Function -> X, Y, Z Surface.

You can then go to the Last Operation options panel and enter the necessary equations:

[image: parametric equation for a cycloid]

By playing with U min and U Max you can generate more or less of the cycloid.

[image: parametric equation for two full passes]

If you want just the curve, then set Z to 0 rather than v.  Here's the curve for two  "humps"

[image: cycloid in Blender.]