How to rotate an stick object on its center while its ends fixed on paralel lines using kinematics
There are three sticks.
When we move black stick on the right to left stick (using bone on it in pose mode).
Left black stick also starts to move towards to right black stick. To do that I used copy location with inverse.
But
Blue stick should rotate on its center keeping the red doted ends at black sticks.
I spend some time using bones armatures but could not do it.


maybe add a link or gif to an animation so we see what you mean and how it should move? because i didn't get it...

I am trying to do that animation in blender so ?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165190/how-to-do-trammel-of-archimedes-animation/165246#165246

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/precise-mechanical-rigging-of-two-arms-connected-by-a-rod/78183#78183

Doing it with scripting is possible but I am trying to do it using  bones and kinematics.

I did it without using script.
Also I discovered it could be done using several different bone constrain technics depends on how you want to do it.
The first animation is the exact answer to original question.
Thank me very much.

I used bone.001 to make the movement.
Bone.003 uses copy rotation of Bone.001 as Y axis reverse and
it is child of Bone.002.
Bone.002 is uses copy location of Bone.001 Head/ Tail 1.
When you rotate Bone.001 along Y axis it makes the trick somehow.


