# Blender Path Deform Bone Contraint Deforms Mesh

Tags: bones, constraints, path

I am making a tram model to follow a path, so the "cars" turn naturally. I found this tutorial on Youtube and I have followed it to a "T", but something has gone awry.

When I turn on the bone constraint "track to" to follow the triangle cube thing, the first bone completely distorts the mesh.

I have done it before, using the same copy of Blender 2.84 (the latest "official" release from Blender) and I cannot replicate results. I have no idea what is going on. Is it just Blender being Blender?

The video I am following.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXheGvyEz3A&t=1086s

I would ask the guy directly, but comments are turned off and no contact info available.

Here is link to my blend file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ygb9u15ibomi3h/followpathdistort.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

There is another method for this kind of purpose, which is better than this one, given [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-like-train-on-a-track-snake/133032#133032) by Batfinger. That said your problem is just that your vertices are influenced by other bones, if I select one of the 4 back face vertices, here is what I see (by the way, *Bone* is probably your root bone, you haven't disabled its *Deform* option):

[image]

So simply click on the X button to remove these vertex groups, or use the *Weight Paint Subtract* brush.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried what you said, but it did not seem to change anything on my end. Here are two files where it was working. I assure you, I followed that vid the same as with the new files. With these files I did not do any messing with vertices or weight paint. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0uv7830w9acj3pn/followCurveWork.blend?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x7c87qdazt6dzd/sara1.blend?dl=0

Comment: did you remove all vertex groups except Bone.001 on the 4 vertices? It works fine here

Comment: OK, that is where I goofed. All work now. Thanks again.

I must have added an object or parented wrong. 

I will try other method explained above tomorrow.

Comment: you could also have done it with weight painting, select the armature, then the mesh, then switch to weight paint mode, and select the bones one after another, don't forget to select the root bone or simply deactivate its Deform option

Comment: the advantage of the other option is that if you ever extend the curve it won't move the train, it will stay where it is currently, it may be useful