# How to Rig an Insect Body to a Curve

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves

All.

I'm trying to rig a rather long insect -- a centipede -- in Blender.
As such, I would like to mimic the movement of a centipede, which is pretty much a sine wave. How can i rig the individual segments of the body, including the legs, in a way that the segments follow a sine wave?
The idea is that I have a control bone or empty to move the entire centipede, but while moving, it should wiggle its body in a sine wave pattern.

I have a little test rig with a head and two segments to play with, but I don't really know how to tackle the movement along the sine wave.

Thanks you for the help!

Comment: Batfinger explains here how to make a snake follow a path, maybe it will fit your needs, then just animate the legs: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path

Comment: Thanks a lot @moonboots