# car model is deforming on follow path curve

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging, bezier-curves, path

I have just started learning Car rigged animation by watching this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EQoi4JlCbc&list=PLwOTLVdj6xMb6c-UQltK1Loru0kgJ1BQv&index=3 )

[image]

the car on the path is deforming at curved areas. Can someone please tell me the solution or another quick shortcut to animate a rigged car. [image]

Comment: Although for prior versions of blender, checkout the car rigs of ROUBAL http://3d-synthesis.com/tutorialsenglish.html  hand info in tutorial pdf http://3d-synthesis.com/tutorials/Cars&TrucksAutodriveSystemV7-1-1.pdf  Basically Instead of feeding your car down the curve make a mesh to do this and constrain your car to it. Similarly to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133032/15543

Comment: ..or send an Empty down the curve, and parent your car to it