# How to retain speed on a "follow path" modifier even if the path is scaled up or down?

Tags: animation, modifiers, bezier-curves

I've added "follow path" modifier to my armature and insterted keyframes so that the armature follows the path between 0-100 frames (the offset goes from 0.0 to 1.0).

Everything looks fine until I started tweaking walk animations. Because I need the offset of the follow path modifier to be 1.0 at a later frame it messes up my animations and the scale of my curve.

I've searched for 2 days straight and only found one single video about this very topic but the instructions a bit unclear for me. Right after the 1:25 mark.  [Video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2EaqaMr6Eg)

Is there a better and/or easier way to do this?

Comment: Not sure this is what you want but you can use a vertex that follows the curve with a Curve modifier (and not a Follow Path constraint), and the armature has a Copy Location that forces it to follow the vertex, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path

Comment: Thanks for the reply @moonboots, your solution (most propably my implementation) yields an offset between this "helper" object and the origin of it. Tried to set a new origin to this object but to no avail. The vertices follows the path but when I apply "copy location" modifier to my armature, it only follows the origin of the helper object. Visuals; https://imgur.com/RkUeLH8