# Blender Mesh/Modifier Animation to Bone/Keyframe Animation

Tags: animation, armature, game-engine, bezier-curves, keyframes

I build a Chain that is following a Curve with the help of some Emptys, like here [Link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path). It works fine, but i need the Animation as a NLA Track on my Armature because i want to use the Animation in Unity or Unreal Engine. I did try to bake it down with the (Bake Action) function but these results in a weird Animation who is only Showing Rotation Values in the end.
So my Question: is there any way to bake or Convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an armature. Constraint bone positions to empties. Those empties are children of your curve points (hooks).
You can only export deforming BONES.
An extensive series about this subject is here> https://youtu.be/hdGkKbtQxE0