# Rigging control: How to animate two snakes twisting along a shared axis (Question)

Tags: animation, rigging

I've watched some snake animation tutorials on youtube and I've manages to control my snake with inverse kinematics. I'm having issues to get it to twist along it's own axis, so to animate two snakes twistinst together along a shared single axis, like the rod of Asklepios (see pic).

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: does it mean that it follows a sinusoid curve and rotate on itself? could you please be more precise?

Comment: Mostly rotating it myself. But I'm happy to hear multiple approaches :)

Comment: instead of using an armature you could simply make them follow a curve? (with a Curve modifier)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rig your object you can take a look at Batfinger's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path).

A simpler solution is to give your object a *Curve* modifier:

[image]

Then if you move your object on Z, here is what happens:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But still I would like to rig it myself! Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: if you want it to be rigged, take a look at Batfinger's answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path

Comment: Thank but I think maybe I need to rephrase my question. How can I control the rotation of mutliple armatures of a snake with a single bone. So when I use that bone all the selected armatures rotate simultanously. What you sient is how a snake could follow a path.

Comment: so maybe reformulate your original question to make as clear as possible

Comment: I did. Thank you for your suggested solution, but that's not what I'm looking for.