# How do i go about rigging this?

Tags: rigging

So I have this object that needs mechanical a rig, It's called an "overhead power and free conveyor". it's used to carry the car to dip in different liquids before it gets painted. I'm trying to create a rig (this entire thing is supposed to follow path as well). I'm pretty new to rigging and this is kind of overwhelming for me to understand. Basically the rounded points are rotation points and the bellow part should also move up and down based on the pivot points above. I'm also adding a link to the model as it would probably be hard to explain without one, here's the link for it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yt1V-qQpg_ZZo8R6sq1xR4rZTB9ha2qG?usp=sharing [image: overhead power and free conveyor]

Comment: maybe you should link us an animation how it should move and look like. I am not totally sure how it should move and animate. thx

Comment: @Chris Right, makes sense. I'm adding the another file to the link, please have a look. i used follow path on the bunch of empties and then used parent constraint on the objects so they follow. Please use the same link I've uploaded a new file there.

Comment: So you want to make an animation like this? https://youtu.be/eHmWHKGRJXc I would scale down the overhead conveyor. In your file, it's over 2700 meters long.

Comment: @Blunder Cool, I can reduce the scale of everything. But i still want to rig it. Is there a way to do it though?

Comment: You can probably rig it like a train but I don't know how to make it follow a path then. Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/133012/107598

Comment: @Blunder I tried to create this and I don't think this will work. I think I'm gonna go with the empties method I used for the example. Is there a way I can animate this follow path at once? In the example I offset the follow path position for each object at the beginning and the at the to maintain the same distance, just wanna know if i can ease the process by a driver perhaps which controls all the instances of follow path?

Comment: OK, after messing for a while i've now come to the conclusion that i can't possibly do this unless i do some manual animation. Because there seems to be no way for me to rig an object like this and attach it to a path. Even my follow path method can kind struck out as the object rotates from it's object center and the edges of this train are not connected when they move down. The closest this worked for me so far is in the example file i uploaded. No other method seems to be working. Please let me know if anyone figures out at some point.