# Is it possible to export a keyframed Geometry Nodes object to GLTF and keep the animation?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, export, gltf, three.js

I have an animated GN setup that just has one value keyframed, that I want to use in a ThreeJS project. I got to the point where it successfully exports the geometry into the gltf file, but it isn't animated.

When the gltf file is imported again it has two keyframes at the start and end just like the original project but they don't change nor animate anything. Is this possible and maybe I'm just missing something? Or should I approach it differently?

This is a simplified video of what I want to export:

[image]

If this isn't possible with geometry nodes I am open to using a different method, but so far the GN setup gives me the most control and I would like to keep that

Comment: Anything other than object transform and mesh deformed by either an armature or shape keys is almost **never** supported by exchange formats and other softwares. The only reliable formats for dynamic meshes are Alembic and USD. But these formats are not supported by every software. Alembic is more present in VFX industry, while USD comes from feature film animation. That being said, **your animation could be done with bones** that follow a curve, which itself can probably be shaped Geometry Nodes, but that isn't in my skill set, so I will leave that part of the answer to other people.

Comment: Maybe you can check this topic for how to deform a chain of bones from a cruve or mesh: [animation - Line of Bones to Travel and Conform to Curve (Train or snake following path) - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path)

Comment: Probably the best way to do it - build model using javaScript in TreeJS